# Which approaches are known to extract product / service data from previously unknown webpages via machine-learning?

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping

To avoid reinventing the wheel, which approaches are known to extract product information / service information from previously unknown webpages via machine-learning?

Which keywords in a search engine might give me better results about this topic?

Comment: One method is making a list of all the words and stripping out simple ones like 'is'. Websites might use meta-tags too :-)

Comment: @StijnDeSmet Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

One method is the following:

1. take a raw html page
2. strip all html/script tag
3. count all words and placing them in a list
4. strip all common words like 'is', 'that', 'we',..
5. Then you do what you have to do with your keywords.. If you want to crawl you take all links and repeat the procedure

Most webpages have meta-tags in de head-section, those might be useful too:

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="webpage with product content">
<meta name="keywords" content="Cameras">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: What I dislike about this approach is that it is not very robust. Keywords-Tags are not frequently being used. Also, the stripping approach just might solve the "find the appropriate products-site"-problem but not the "extract/scrape products/services properly given a wide variety of product content placement and formatting" - problem.

Comment: I think if you really want to scrape products that you will have to write a crawler with a separate template per website system.